# Communicating with MSADO on older machines

Tags: c++, windows

I'm writing a small MFC application to talk to Access databases using the ADO method. Problem is it works on some computers (mostly newer, Windows 7 SP1) but not on older ones, and I really need to fix this or I don't have a application.

The error is a typically informative "App has stopped working", so no news there.

I initially import the database using

```
#import "libid:B691E011-1797-432E-907A-4D8C69339129" \
rename( "EOF", "AdoNSEOF" )
```

which is the UUID for MSAdo60.tlb. I connect to it using the following connection string:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+dbPath+";
```

Both machines have both msado15.dll and mado60.tlb. I'll need to check versions.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2517589

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work unfortuantely. Dropping the UUID back to msado15.dll has however, or that and the combination of 2517589.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved this with knowledge base 2640696 and dropping the UUID for msado15.dll. Microsoft considerately broken the interface moving to W7SP1.